# Why is "בבהילו יצאנו ממצרים" a mix of two paraphrases?

Tags: rambam, passover-seder-hagada, targumin, parashat-reeh

Included in [the *Rambam*'s *hagada* text](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/3509.htm) is the line

> בבהילו יצאנו ממצרים‎,

replicated in some modern *hagados*. This line blends near-quotations of [*D'varim* 16:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0516.htm#3),

> כִּי בְחִפָּזוֹן יָצָאתָ מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרַיִם‎,

and of [its *targum Onkelus*](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/k/q/q0516.htm#3),

> ארי בבהילו נפקתא מארעא דמצרים‎.

It's curious for a number of reasons, but the aspect of it that I find most curious is that it's a mixture of the original *Chumash* text and the *targum Onkelus*. Why didn't the *Rambam* (or whomever he got that line from) choose the one source ("בבהילו נפקנא ממצרים") or the other ("בחפזון יצאנו ממצרים")?

(I do recognize that [mixing Hebrew and Aramaic is common in *Rambam*-era works](/a/37643). But this is a partial paraphrase of the Torah and a partial paraphrase of the *targum*, which strikes me as very odd. Why not pick one source and stick with it?)

Comment: I think you have the answer there in your question.  This was not likely a purposeful mix of the Targum and Mikra, but rather likely something that people said based on how they spoke then.